# Angular / PHP / mysql Web App Conversion to Mobile App via Capacitor

Tags: php, angular, capacitor, mobile-application

I have a very complex Angular web application hosted on Siteground. My frontend is Angular, my backend is PHP, and the database is stored on Siteground.

I am looking for any insight into how to convert this entire application into a mobile app for both iOS and Android.

I have thus far been able to successfully bundle my Angular frontend using Capacitor into an android app in Android Studio and the front end works as expected.

However, it does not have the php code or database data required to be a functional app -- it is just the shell of the frontend without any data.

Comment: Do you indent for your app to be an offline app? Many apps are simply the front end making API calls to your PHP server that is publically hosted. So they don't need PHP or a database on their local device.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to mobile development. If that is the best method for mobile apps, then that would suffice -- making API calls to my PHP server. 

Now, what is confusing to me is I thought this is what was already happening on my web application (so I was hopeful the mobile would simply, well, work). I have angular services that call my PHP files which then access and manipulate the data and return it. 

Do you know what the difference is between mobile / web for this connection? Or could point me in the right direction on how to fix this connection for mobile?

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm missing some setting in capacitor that sets up this connection? Or could it be that my server is rejecting the mobile app incoming "url" request?

Comment: Hey Kristina, you need to add some code to your question so that we can look for a solution together.

Comment: I believe my new issue is that my android studio application cannot hit the API I have set up even though I can hit it on my bundled angular app (browser) and postman. Are there any tips or tricks to making an android studio application hit an API that I could be missing? I have the INTERNET enabled thing in my config settings already...

Comment: I can provide code if you let me know what would be helpful for me to provide.